# Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicontrol

When I compiling the following code:

```
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let selectedBackgroundWidth = bounds.width / 2.0 - selectedBackgroundInset * 2.0
    selectedBackgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: selectedBackgroundInset + CGFloat(selectedIndex) * (selectedBackgroundWidth + selectedBackgroundInset * 2.0), y: selectedBackgroundInset, width: selectedBackgroundWidth, height: bounds.height - selectedBackgroundInset * 2.0)

    (titleLabelsContentView.frame, selectedTitleLabelsContentView.frame) = (bounds, bounds)

    let titleLabelMaxWidth = bounds.width / 2.0 - selectedBackgroundInset * 2.0
    let titleLabelMaxHeight = bounds.height - selectedBackgroundInset * 2.0

    let leftTitleLabelSize = leftTitleLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: titleLabelMaxWidth, height: titleLabelMaxHeight))
    let leftTitleLabelOrigin = CGPoint(x: floor((bounds.width / 2.0 - leftTitleLabelSize.width) / 2.0), y: floor((bounds.height - leftTitleLabelSize.height) / 2.0))
    let leftTitleLabelFrame = CGRect(origin: leftTitleLabelOrigin, size: leftTitleLabelSize)
    (leftTitleLabel.frame, selectedLeftTitleLabel.frame) = (leftTitleLabelFrame, leftTitleLabelFrame)

    let rightTitleLabelSize = rightTitleLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: titleLabelMaxWidth, height: titleLabelMaxHeight))
    let rightTitleLabelOrigin = CGPoint(x: floor(bounds.size.width / 2.0 + (bounds.width / 2.0 - rightTitleLabelSize.width) / 2.0), y: floor((bounds.height - rightTitleLabelSize.height) / 2.0))
    let rightTitleLabelFrame = CGRect(origin: rightTitleLabelOrigin, size: rightTitleLabelSize)
    (rightTitleLabel.frame, selectedRightTitleLabel.frame) = (rightTitleLabelFrame, rightTitleLabelFrame)
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
```

I tried the code in a different project and it compiles without problems.

**How do I solve this problem?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to separate your calculation like this:

```
let rightTitleLabelSize = rightTitleLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: titleLabelMaxWidth, height: titleLabelMaxHeight))
let x = floor(bounds.size.width / 2.0 + (bounds.width / 2.0 - rightTitleLabelSize.width) / 2.0)
let y = floor((bounds.height - rightTitleLabelSize.height) / 2.0)
let rightTitleLabelOrigin = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
let rightTitleLabelFrame = CGRect(origin: rightTitleLabelOrigin, size: rightTitleLabelSize)
(rightTitleLabel.frame, selectedRightTitleLabel.frame) = (rightTitleLabelFrame, rightTitleLabelFrame)
```

Comment: @confile Notice that is is easier to understand, verify correctness and debug! These are attributes of good code.